# how to set method to get total length for each points

Tags: python, oop

I need to provide a length() method for the Polygon class that returns the total length of the polygon's outline by summing up the distances from each point to the next, including the distance from the last point back to first point. eg:3 point polygon poly = Poly(p1, p2, p3), poly.length() should return distance from p1 to p2 plus the distance from  p2 to p3 plus the distance from p3 to p1. 
how should I set the length()method in oop?
here is my code:

```
class Polygon:
def __init__(self, points=[]): # init with list of points
    print("creating an instance of class", self.__class__.__name__)
    self.point_list = points[:]  # list to store a sequence of points

def draw(self):
    turtle.penup()
    for p in self.point_list:
        p.draw()
        turtle.pendown()
    # go back to first point to close the polygon
    self.point_list[0].draw()

def num_points(self):
    return len(point_list)
```

Thanks

so I already defined a dist() method thatreturns the 2D distance to a given point:

```
def dist(self, other):
    dis_x = (other.x - self.x)*(other.x - self.x) 
    dis_y = (other.y - self.y)*(other.y - self.y)
    dis_new = math.sqrt(dis_x + dis_y)
    return dis_new
```

but still get stuck in how to get total length of the outline from each points...

Comment: Use the Pythagorean theorem to get the distances, then add them up? Without seeing your code or how you're storing the poliygon's points, there is no way to answer this.

Comment: hi, I just updated my original code

Answer (score 0):

If you're purely looking for the structure of classes and methods, then you have a few options. You could either have a `length()` method of the `Poly` class as you've said, or you could have a dynamic property which runs a function underneath.

Using your proposal:

```
class Poly(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            # Do something with each side
            print(arg)

    def length(self):
        return get_length_of_perimeter()
```

You can then call this like:

```
poly = Poly(p1, p2, p3)
print(poly.length())
```

Or you can use the `@property` decorator to return the function as if it was a property:

```
class Poly(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            # Do something with each side
            print(arg)

    @property
    def length(self):
        return get_length_of_perimeter()
```

Which you will then call like:

```
poly = Poly(p1, p2, p3)
print(poly.length)  # notice you're not calling length as if it was a method
```